# Share a post in a page to a group?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to automate a post to a group using the Facebook API but I can't figure out how to do the next scenario:

I manually post to my client's page a post with a link (with all the rich media Open Graph gives you: the preview, title, etc.). Once I've this post, I would like to do the next: as if I was a user of the website, share the post to a group.

Is that possible? I can't figure out a way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use `user_managed_groups` to authorize and check out the docs for information on how to post to the group: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#publish

The docs include code examples for the most important programming languages.

Btw, you should only do this on groups you manage, it will most likely count as spam in other groups.